# Mahalanobis distance of point to plane algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry, euclidean-distance

I am trying to understand the Mahalanobis distance of a point from the plane given by this [paper](https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2012-13/F/6338/lectures/mahalanobis_distance_to_plane.pdf). The algorithm is given below:

1. Calculate covariance of point $S_{uu}$
2. Apply a whitening transform to the covariance matrix using SVD where $S_{uu} = RVR^T$. $R$ is the rotation matrix and $V$ is the scale $V = diag(a^2, b^2, c^2)$
3. The output is transformed into 3 homogenous 4x4 matrices

$Rh = \begin{bmatrix} R & 0 \\ 0^T & 1 \end{bmatrix}, Th = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -u^T & 1 \end{bmatrix}, Ah = diag(a,b,c,1)$

where $u$ is the point under consideration.

4. The transformed plane is given by $q = Ah*Rh*Th*p$ where p is the planar parameters

5 . The transformed plane distance to the center of the unit sphere is given as:

$d_M = \frac{q_4}{\sqrt{q_1^2 + q_2^2 + q_3^2}}$

My first question is regarding the whitening transform. I am not sure how it is being derived (its not given in the paper). If anyone can provide an intuitive explanation, that would be great.

My second question is - I simulated a plane with planar parameters [0, 0, 1] and points on the plane with std error of 0.02. [image] We can recover the planar parameters using svd. Now, when I run the algorithm to get the transformed plane using the following code:

```
# whitening transform of point covariance
cov_pts = np.cov(pts.transpose())
r, v, rt = np.linalg.svd(cov_pts)
abc = np.sqrt(v)
ah = np.diag(v=np.concatenate((abc, np.array([1]))))
rh = np.zeros((4, 4))
rh[0:3, 0:3] = r
rh[3, 3] = 1
th = np.eye(4)
th[3, 0:3] = -center
transformed_plane_fit = np.dot(np.matmul(np.matmul(ah, rh), th),
                                       np.concatenate((plane_fit, np.array([1]))))
```

the values I get for transformed planar fit is $-0.029929, -0.000731, -0.019731, -0.911577$, which don't seem to correspond to the planar parameters. What can be the reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: The idea here is that you have a known plane, and a point with an uncertain location, represented by its covariance matrix. The matrix that you should be performing SVD on is this covariance matrix, not a matrix constructed from points in the plane. Similarly, `center` should be the coordinates of the point that you are testing against the known plane. Is that correct?

Comment: That is exactly correct.

Comment: OK. I'm checking, because it wasn't clear that `pts` is the uncertainty of a single point being tested. So ignore the specific numbers of the transformed plane. Test it against the unit sphere and what happens?

Comment: I am computing the uncertainty of the single point from the surrounding points. Testing against the unit sphere (I have updated the code to add the distance formula) gives large distance measure which is not possible.